# Azure DevOps Agent pools - create for project only

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When I create an Agent Pool in any of my DevOps projects I will see the pool also in the other projects in the same organization. How to disable this behaviour? I want each Agent Pool to be accessible only by the selected project.

Answer (score 0):

for agent pool and self-hosted agent setting, both for [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#server-url), mac and [windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#server-url-and-authentication), you need to enter organization URL when configure the agent. So you need to go to organization settings->Agent pools->click the affected agent pool then go to Security, to limit other projects users' permission to read the agent pool.

Here in my example, if I remove other project\project valid users and only leave project A\project valid users as readers, only users in project A could see the affected pool in the organization level and other projects' agent pools.

Users in other projects will not be able to see the agent pool, unless you add the individual user as at least reader role in the security part.
[image]

I hope it could do some help.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my issue. The scope of the agent pool here is defined using permissions. I need to be able to create "XXX" agent pool in project 1 and put there "YYY" agent and then create again "XXX" agent pool in project 2 but put there different agent "ZZZ". So I need 2 pools to be completely separated.

Comment: As I previously explained, since the self-hosted agent be configured into organization level, you are not supported to create two agent pool with same name but different agents in different projects but one organization. The name should be unique. If you do need the feature, We recommend that you can directly report the feature requests:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=22&entry=suggestion. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate engineering team, and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.